# SASS Errors during Angular 14 to Angular 16 upgrade

Tags: angular, sass

I'm totally new to SASS Errors, leveraging Dependabot and CodeQL to handle security vulnerabilities, please bear with me.

Background info: (how I got to this question :) )

The overall task is to experiment with Dependabot and CodeQL in our Enterprise account.  I've copied one of our new Angular apps to another folder locally and pushed it into a repo on our GitHub Enterprise.

I'm finally down to the Dependabot alerts that do not automatically resolve.  Some of these have to do with moving from Angular 14 to Angular 16.

I have a separate branch for upgrading to Angular 16.

The step of the upgrade I'm at is 14 to 15.
[Upgrade Path](https://update.angular.io/?v=14.0-16.0)

Testing compile with npm start after upgrading to Angular 15, I get these errors:

[image: SASS Errors]

I handled others.  @Import is replaced with @use per another SO Article.  When this was done, all @use rules had to occur first.

What is left are the 2 errors above.

I've also put in a bug report, it could be the upgrade path has had breaking changes happen.

[Bug Report on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-update-guide/issues/239)

Since all instances of @Import are now @Use in all stylesheets in the project, I don't see how the @Import "~@progress/kendo- ..." happens.  My guess is @Import is somehow added by default here? (See 2nd error in the image)

Tried replacing ~ with /node_modules/ or ./node_modules/ per another SO article, this didn't resolve the error.

The resolution to these errors should be straightforward, I just don't know SASS well enough.

Have not found a KB resource yet that explains what is up.  That's what I could use, is a link to whatever articles on SASS that get quickly to the point on how to deal with this.

Thanks!

/*** Just thought of another thing ***/

See here in the image where the upgrade to Angular 15 happens.  Note, there is no step here to run npm start.  But there are steps to continue on.

Just in case doing npm start at this point was an error, I'll run the rest of the upgrade to 16. Who's to say it won't work?

[image: Upgrade Steps]

Actually, 2nd step from the bottom says to check V15 out prior to update to V16 :).

Oh well ...

Comment: looks like there is an issue with kendo-theme styles. Did you try upgrading kendo as well?

Comment: No, that has not been tried.  Thanks, will try this and put the results in this post.

Comment: Survey says -- no joy :)  Ran this: npx npm-check-updates --upgrade --filter "/@progress.*/"

It did do quite a few updates, for instance Kendo buttons was updated from 8.1.0 to 14.1.0 -- quite a jump.

Ran npm start right after, same results.

Comment: hi @user1585204 how did you fix the issues then?